# AttributeError: type object 'Database' has no attribute 'scoreDB'

Tags: python, amazon-rds, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to Python using AWS RDS during the process of making games using pygame and open source. When I run it, it says "AttributeError: type object 'Database' has no attribute 'scoreDB' "

**shooting_game.py**

```py
import pygame
from database import Database

def main():
    hiScores=Database().getScores()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while(main()):
        pass
```

**database.py**

```py
import pymysql

class Database(object):
    numScores = 15
    def __init__(self,host='database-1.c79ahye2go7m.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com',user='admin',password='letskirin',db='hiScores',charset='utf8'):
        self.scoreDB=pymysql.connect(host=host,user=user,password=password,db=db,charset=charset)
        self.cursor=self.scoreDB.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    @staticmethod
    def getSound(self,music=False):
        curs = self.scoreDB.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        if music:
            curs.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists music (setting integer)")
            curs.execute("SELECT * FROM music")
        else:
            curs.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists sound (setting integer)")
            curs.execute("SELECT * FROM sound")
        self.scoreDB.commit()
        setting = curs.fetchall()
        curs.close()
        return bool(setting[0][0]) if len(setting) > 0 else False

    @staticmethod
    def setSound(self,setting, music=False):
        curs = self.scoreDB.cursor()
        if music:
            curs.execute("DELETE FROM music")
            curs.execute("INSERT INTO music VALUES (?)", (setting,))
        else:
            curs.execute("DELETE FROM sound")
            curs.execute("INSERT INTO sound VALUES (?)", (setting,))
        self.scoreDB.commit()
        curs.close()

    @classmethod
    def getScores(self):
        curs = self.scoreDB.cursor()

        curs.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists scores
                     (name text, score integer, accuracy real)''')
        curs.execute("SELECT * FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC")
        self.scoreDB.commit()
        hiScores = curs.fetchall()
        curs.close()
        return hiScores

    @staticmethod
    def setScore(self,hiScores,entry):
        curs = self.scoreDB.cursor()

        if len(hiScores) == Database.numScores:
            lowScoreName = hiScores[-1][0]
            lowScore = hiScores[-1][1]
            curs.execute("DELETE FROM scores WHERE (name = ? AND score = ?)",
                      (lowScoreName, lowScore))
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO scores VALUES (?,?,?)", entry)
        self.scoreDB.commit()
        curs.close()
```

**ERROR message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\giuni27\ossp\Base_shooting-game\shooting_game.py", line 683, in <module>
    while(main()):
  File "c:\Users\giuni27\ossp\Base_shooting-game\shooting_game.py", line 127, in main
    hiScores=Database.getScores()
  File "c:\Users\giuni27\ossp\Base_shooting-game\database.py", line 43, in getScores
    curs = self.scoreDB.cursor()
AttributeError: type object 'Database' has no attribute 'scoreDB
```

I tried to find the reason and implement it as it is, but I couldn't fix the error. I would appreciate it if you could help me with a beginner developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you used the decorator @classmethod, when you use this, your are saying that this is a static method, and you are tryng to acess a object method
Solution: remove the decorator  @classmethod of getScores(self)
method

Comment: "when you use [@classmethod], your are saying that this is a static method"—Python also has a [`staticmethod` function / decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod). How are `classmethod` and `staticmethod` related?

Comment: Sorry @Mateus Moutinho I'm here as well. I was just checking python tag and it got me here again. Class methods and static methods are not the same. Class variables and static variables are same. Class methods deal with classes whereas static methods are independent of class and instance

Comment: in pratical, its almost the same thing kkkk